# How do I switch arrow types in Towerfall?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

In Towerfall, whenever you pick up a new arrow type it is moved to the front of your arrow list. This means if I pick up 2 bomb arrows from a chest, I’ll need to use both bomb arrows before I can fire my normal arrows again.

Is there any way to switch between arrow types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press a button at any time to switch between arrow types in your inventory.

- Keyboard: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Xbox 360 Controller: Ⓨ
- PS3 Controller (*unconfirmed*): △

As far as I know, this option is never mentioned in-game. [Credit to Junderland for discovering this](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=315480214).